# Which is the first government to have monetized government debt in order to fund government debt without paying a high interest rate?

Tags: japan, finance

> So, how has Japan managed to sustain itself in the face of such
> mounting debt? The answer lies in a clever strategy employed by the
> Japanese government. **They use a scheme of monetizing government debt,
> where the Bank of Japan purchases government bonds to finance the
> government’s spending needs. This, in turn, keeps interest rates low.
> These low interest rates allow the government to avoid spending a
> significant portion of its income on repaying these bonds.**

https://www.deccanherald.com/world/japan-s-debt-dilemma-and-its-balancing-act-2750760

> Table 2 presents these calculations for each year since 2000, a period
> during which both debt accumulation and the monetisation of this debt
> were proceeding rapidly. General government debt rose by 20 per cent
> of GDP during this three-year period, but the BOJ’s true net worth
> also increased during this period. In all, the consolidated net debt
> of the general government and central bank increased from 45 per cent
> of GDP in 2000 to 62 per cent in 2003.

https://www.publicdebtnet.org/export/sites/pdm/pdm/ECONOMIC-ANALYSES-AND-POLICIES/Economic-Policies/Documents/da-p.-901-a-p.-920---Lebow.pdf

Which is the first government to have monetized government debt in order to fund government debt without paying a high interest rate? Is Japan the first country? I see that they did it in 2000, but I don't know if they did monetize even earlier during the 90s. I am wondering if Japan was the first country to have done it, or another government did it before Japan.

Comment: Isn't this just "printing money" with extra steps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Question:**
>
> Which is the first government to have monetized government debt in order to fund government debt without paying a high interest rate?

All debt which can be represented as currency by definition is monetized.  What the Japanese are doing is called financing their debt.  The government can't purchase all the debt and keep interest rates low as your source describes.  It would be great if they could, everyone would do it; but that violates a fundamental principle of economics.  What nations strives for is a balance between government held debt, private held debt, across foreign and domestic debt holders.  What you describe is like the perpetual motion machine, great in theory but doesn't exist in reality.

Who was the first to use modern economics and financing to fund their government.  Probable the United Kingdom.  They were the first industrialized country and the first to document modern economics.  **[The Wealth of Nations](https://www.britannica.com/topic/the-Wealth-of-Nations)**, Adam Smith 1776.  The first formulation of a comprehensive system of political economy.

See Book V, “**[Of the Revenue of the Sovereign or Commonwealth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934084050)**,” in which Smith outlines the four main stages of organized governments the fourth and final stage is commercial interdependence.  In which economics and modern finance comes into play.

Comment: FWIW, I agree that monetizing the national debt doesn't mean what the OP article suggests that it does, and doesn't have the claimed effects.

Answer (score 1):

A better explanation than monetization, for low interest rates in Japan on government debt, is that Japanese investors are risk averse and don't have very good alternatives to safe investments with only slight returns. Without competition for investable funds, the government can get away with paying low interest rates.

According to a [Nikkei Asia story of December 26, 2023](https://asia.nikkei.com/Economy/Japan-households-investments-drive-80-of-asset-growth) (emphasis added):

> Japanese households are putting a growing share of their assets into
> investments like equities and bonds **as rising domestic and U.S.
> stock markets and a weak yen encourage a shift away from a
> long-standing preference for cash**.
>
> Investment assets -- stocks, investment trusts, bonds and foreign
> securities . . . reached an all-time high of 427 trillion yen, making
> up 20.2% of households' financial assets -- the biggest share since
> September 2007, prior to the global financial crisis. **Half of its
> 160 trillion yen gain over the past decade came in the past year
> alone.**

In other words, Japanese consumers have invested less than 20% of their savings in stocks, investment trusts, bonds and foreign securities at all times in the last 16 years, and 50% of the returns on those investments over the last decade took place in 2023 alone, as the dam has finally broken on faith in these riskier investments. Despite their small share of the market, these investments provided 82% of all investment returns in Japan in 2023.

By comparison, U.S. investors are more likely to have non-cash investments and invest more in these kinds of investments as illustrated by [2021 data from the U.S. Census Bureau](https://www.census.gov/content/dam/Census/library/publications/2023/demo/p70br-183.pdf):

[image]

According to the OECD no other capitalists countries in the world except Greece and Turkey have such a large share of its nation's total consumer savings and investment tied up in postal savings accounts, and other investments by Japanese investors are disproportionately in very safe, income oriented, low interest rate investments. (The U.S., meanwhile, is second only to Iceland in the lower percentage of its financial investments that are in cash deposits.)

[image]

While Japan does have publicly traded equities that are traded on a stock market and higher risk investment options available (such as directly investing in closely held businesses), the overall volume of these investments compared to other Western-style capitalist economies, and the percentage of the population making these kinds of investments, is much smaller.

Comment: Japan offers large tax incentives domestically for it's citizens to save money.   The **[primary beneficiary of this 9 year old policy is the U.S. stock markets  NASDAQ](https://www.reuters.com/markets/asia/kishidas-nisa-bet-is-paying-off-just-not-japanese-stocks-2023-11-30/)**  which is the more "conservative investment".   "Overseas stocks dominate the popular investment product rankings at online Japanese brokerages, such as the Monex Group and SBI Securities."

Comment: @JMS Even with these tax incentives (which, of course, the U.S. has as well with favorable tax treatment for all kinds of unearned income), the Japanese just weren't investing much in stocks and private bonds, especially prior to 2023, because they were far more risk averse.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @JMS While this is purely speculative, some causes for the risk aversion may include the huge losses of financial assets in WWII and subsequent post-war economic collapses, one of the oldest populations in the world with a large percentage of adults on fixed incomes, and a very weak government safety net (with big business employers filling a big share of the role filled by government in other Western economies). Also, a large percentage of Japanese salaries are in the form of year end bonuses that vary unpredictably, a risk that needs to be buffered against.